# Is it need to generate Task.Token by step function or stepfunction automatically generates Task.Token

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I want to generate Task.Token. May I know how to create Task.Token to invoke lambda function. Is sf automaically generates Task.Token along with "Payload":{ "TaskToken.$": "$.Task.Token" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup .. it is automatically generated for WaitForToken if your task have relevant keyword attached to it.

Sample from  aws, in below example Task have shown that it needs to wait for taskToken in line arn:aws:states:::sqs:sendMessage.waitForTaskToken

```
"Send message to SQS": {
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::sqs:sendMessage.waitForTaskToken",
  "Parameters": {
    "QueueUrl": "https://sqs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/123456789012/myQueue",
    "MessageBody": {
        "Message": "Hello from Step Functions!",
        "TaskToken.$": "$$.Task.Token"
     }
  },
  "Next": "NEXT_STATE"
}
```